# Workaround for template argument deduction in non-deduced context

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct outer {
    struct inner {};
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & stream, 
                         typename outer<T>::inner const& value) {
    std::cout << "An outer::inner!";
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    outer<float>::inner foo;

    std::cout << foo << std::endl; // does not compile
}
```

This does not compile, because `typename outer<T>::inner` is a *nondeduced context* (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here)), meaning the template-argument-type cannot be deduced by the compiler (read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4975785/160206) for the why). As I see it, I have two options to make it work:

1. Move `inner` outside of `outer` and make it a class-template. I prefer this one, because the impact on the using code is smaller.
2. Add a `to_string`-method to inner.

Are there any other solutions for this (that do not result in ugly syntax in the using code)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can move the operator into the inner class body and put `friend` before it. Then replace the parameter type by just `inner`.

Another technique is to derive inner from a CRTP base parameterized by inner. Then make the parameter type the CRTP class and cast the parameter reference to the derived `inner` class, the type of which is given by the template argument you deduce.

Comment: The `friend`-approach works fine. I was not aware that you can define a function in a `friend`-declaration (for those who are interested: I just looked it up, it is defined in §11.4.5 of the 2003 standard).