# ostream operator << for a subclass of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, iostream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the template argument deduction not working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268504/why-is-the-template-argument-deduction-not-working-here)
>   [Workaround for non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308213/workaround-for-non-deduced-context)

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    struct I
    {
        T t;
    };
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const typename S<T>::I& i)
{
    out << i;
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    S<int>::I i;
    std::cout << i;
}
```

This code fails in Visual Studio 2010, as the << operator cannot be found. Is it possible to create an output operator for S::I?

Comment: I had [exactly the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308213/workaround-for-non-deduced-context) recently.The cause is that `S<int>::I` is a non-deduced context.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose it is better to close this question.