# Template parameter specialization problems with operator!=

Tags: c++, templates

I have an STL-style iterator on a template sparse matrix class I wrote, `YaleStorage<D>`. I have written an `operator==` for the matrix class which allows for two matrices to be compared for which `D` may differ.

My iterators are also templates -- so I can have `const_iterator` and `iterator` as specializations of `iterator_T<RefType>`, where `RefType` may be either `const D&` or `D&`.

I need these iterators to be comparable even when `D` differs. I don't particularly need constness to differ (a `const_iterator` does not need to be compared to an `iterator`). Here's how I wrote the `operator!=` and such:

```
template <typename D>
class YaleStorage {
  template <typename RefType>
  class iterator_T {
    template <typename E, typename ERefType = typename enable_if_else<std::is_const<RefType>::value, const E&, E&>::type>
    bool operator!=(const typename YaleStorage<E>::template stored_diagonal_iterator_T<ERefType>& rhs) const { /* some comparison code */ }
  };
  typedef iterator_T<D&>       iterator;
  typedef iterator_T<const D&> const_iterator;

  const_iterator cbegin() const { /* returns a const_iterator */ }
  const_iterator cend() const { /* returns the end const_iterator */ }
};
```

Note that I wrote my own `enable_if_else`, since I couldn't find a similar function in the STL. Here is that:

```
template <bool B, typename TA, typename TB>
struct enable_if_else {};
template <typename TA, typename TB>
struct enable_if_else<true, TA, TB> {  typedef TA type; };
template <typename TA, typename TB>
struct enable_if_else<false, TA, TB> { typedef TB type; };
```

Unfortunately, when I try to do a regular iterator comparison (where `D=E`), I get a whole raft of errors, such as:

```
compiling ../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp: In instantiation of ‘VALUE nm::yale_storage::each_stored_with_indices(VALUE) [with DType = unsigned char; VALUE = long unsigned int]’:
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp:1686:3:   required from here
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp:1567:83: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘d != nm::YaleStorage<D>::cend() const [with D = unsigned char; nm::YaleStorage<D>::const_iterator = nm::YaleStorage<unsigned char>::iterator_T<const unsigned char&>]()’
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp:1567:83: note: candidates are:
In file included from ../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp:64:0:
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.h:438:10: note: template<class E, class ERefType> bool nm::YaleStorage<D>::iterator_T::operator!=(const typename nm::YaleStorage<E>::iterator_T<ERefType>&) const [with E = E; ERefType = ERefType; RefType = const unsigned char&; D = unsigned char]
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.h:438:10: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
../../../../ext/nmatrix/storage/yale.cpp:1567:83: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘E’
```

I've tried explicitly casting the result of `cend()` so it knows what's on both sides of the comparison, but I can't see why it'd choke on this.

```
template <typename DType>
static VALUE each_with_indices(VALUE nm) {
  YaleStorage<DType> y(s);

  // The next line is 1567:
  for (typename YaleStorage<DType>::const_iterator d = y.cbegin(); d != y.cend()); ++d) {
    /* Do some stuff with d */
  }
}
```

I know how to explicitly specify template parameters for non-`operator` functions, but how do I do it for operators? Is there another, better approach? It seems to me that it should be obvious to the compiler what `E` is here.

Comment: `enable_if_else` sounds like a duplicate of C++11's [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Comment: It looks like `E` is in a non-deduced context in your `operator!=` (non-deduced because you're using a nested type as the parameter type).

Comment: Can you use C++11 features?

Comment: Turning `iterator_T` into a non-nested type could help to simplify your issue. Is that possible in your case?

Comment: @DyP Oops! Looked everywhere for `std::conditional`. Thanks.

I suppose I could make the iterators non-nested. When I learned to code 13 years ago, our teacher taught us to make them nested. But I'm not really sure why, honestly.

Comment: As the implementation of the iterator depends on the implementation of the container, it's not a bad idea to make the nested. But you could as well put them in a namespace (not to pollute the namespace surrounding the container). Another solution would be to take any parameter for `operator!=` and inside the function `static_assert` via typedefs in the iterator class (if this is necessary at all).

Comment: You have an instance of *non-deduced context* here (there should be a lot of duplicate questions but I can't find any at the moment).

Comment: I *know* there have to be questions on this, but I haven't been able to find any either. =(

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-template-and-parameter-deducing)? (searched for *deduce nested [c++]*)