# Templated function on templated subclass

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out why gcc cannot deduce the template arguments in the following code:

```
template <int N>
struct A {
    template <int M>
    struct B {
    };
};

template <int N, int M>
void function(typename A<N>::template B<M> &b) {
    // do stuff
}

int main() {
    A<1>::B<2> b;
    function(b);
}
```

**Error**:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:19:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘function(A<1>::B<2>&)’
  function(b);
            ^
test.cpp:19:12: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:13:6: note: template<int N, int M> void function(typename A<N>::B<M>&)
 void function(typename A<N>::template B<M> &b) {
      ^
test.cpp:13:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:19:12: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘N’
  function(b);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling with the c++11 option enabled?

Comment: A<1>::B<2> b(); -- I am always a little unsure about this, but isnt this the most vexing parse?

Comment: I have edited the question and placed the error in the question body.

Comment: In `main`, `b` is a function.

Comment: @PhilippLenk: It's rapidly becoming the mostly parsed vex by now.

Comment: Why the downvote, his question is legit and I think @KerrekSB is correct.

Comment: That was a mistake I made while transferring the code; it is not a function in the code that was executed (fixed in question body).

Comment: Here is what you are looking for:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-template-and-parameter-deducing

Answer (score 0):

I leave this answer mainly because of the comments. The question has apparently been previously [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-template-and-parameter-deducing) and [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640996/369310).

But as a rule of thumb, for template deduction, in my experience use clang as replacement/alternative, it has much better error messages for such issues (like *why* template deduction failed).

Comment: This was a mistake I made while transferring the code. The actual code that was run to produce the error output is "correct" in this sense.

Comment: Ok, still I would suggest using clang to get a 'second opinion' so to speak.

Comment: Thanks, downloading right now

Comment: The clang output was pretty much the same; it said it could not infer the template parameter

Comment: This link explains why you cannot do exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-template-and-parameter-deducing