# C++ Template Inner Class Friend Operator Overload

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I am trying to implement an overload for `operator!=` that compares two objects of different types (`InnerA` and `InnerB`).  Both of the types are defined as nested classes within a template class (`Outer`).  The overload needs to be a friend of both classes as it accesses private fields from each.

```
template<typename Type> class Outer
{
public:
    class InnerA;
    class InnerB;
};


template<typename Type> bool operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerA& lhs, const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& rhs);


template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerA
{
    const int val = 0;
    friend bool operator!=<>(const InnerA& lhs, const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& rhs);
};


template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerB
{
    const int val = 1;
    friend bool operator!=<>(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerA& lhs, const InnerB& rhs);
};


template<typename Type> bool operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerA& lhs, const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& rhs)
{
    return lhs.val != rhs.val;
}


int main()
{
    bool b = Outer<int>::InnerA() != Outer<int>::InnerB();
}
```

The above code fails to compile, emitting:

```
 In instantiation of 'class Outer<int>::InnerA':
34:33: required from here 
15:17: error: template-id 'operator!=<>' for 'bool operator!=(const Outer<int>::InnerA&, const Outer<int>::InnerB&)' does not match any template declaration 
 In instantiation of 'class Outer<int>::InnerB': 
34:57: required from here 
22:17: error: template-id 'operator!=<>' for 'bool operator!=(const Outer<int>::InnerA&, const Outer<int>::InnerB&)' does not match any template declaration 
 In function 'int main()': 
34:35: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'Outer<int>::InnerA' and 'Outer<int>::InnerB') 
34:35: note: candidate is: 
26:30: note: template<class Type> bool operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerA&, const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB&) 
26:30: note: template argument deduction/substitution failed: 
34:57: note: couldn't deduce template parameter 'Type'
```

While there might be better ways to achieve a similar result, I'm curious as to what precisely is wrong with my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the code in the question ended up being that template deduction is not attempted on type names nested inside a dependent type (e.g. `Outer<Type>::Inner`).

This question is essentially a duplicate of [Nested template and parameter deducing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640808/nested-%20template-%20and-%20parameter-%20deducing).  A detailed explanation on why this is a problem can be found [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/p0293r0.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerA
{
   friend bool operator!=(const InnerA& lhs, const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& rhs) { return true; }
};
template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerB
{
  friend bool operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerA& lhs, const InnerB& rhs) { return true; }
};
```

these are non-template friends.  They also conflict.  So implement one of them, omit the other.

They will be found via ADL.

Comment: I don't think this solution will work for my purpose.  The `operator!=` overload needs to be a friend of both `InnerA` and `InnerB` to access private fields from each.  I'll update my question to make that clear.

Comment: @alex Sure, that is an add-on to the question.  To solve that, forward to another non-operator.  An important part of operators is deducing which one to call; non-template friends are easily found via ADL.  Non-deduced context templates, meanwhile, can only be called by passing the types explicitly, which is not what you want in an operator.

Comment: I suppose this boils down to my lacking an adequate understanding of ADL.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround, refactoring the overload as a method of one of the nested classes:

```
template<typename Type> class Outer
{
public:
    class InnerA;
    class InnerB;
};


template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerA
{
    const int val = 0;
public:
    bool operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& other);
};


template<typename Type> class Outer<Type>::InnerB
{
    const int val = 1;
    friend bool Outer<Type>::InnerA::operator!=(const InnerB& other);
};


template<typename Type> bool Outer<Type>::InnerA::operator!=(const typename Outer<Type>::InnerB& other)
{
    return val != other.val;
}


int main()
{
    bool b = Outer<void>::InnerA() != Outer<void>::InnerB();
}
```

However, I am still curious if the same can be accomplished using a non-member friend function as in the question.

Comment: *"I am still curious if the same can be accomplished using a non-member friend function as in the question."*: With `Outer<Type>::InnerA`, `Type` cannot be deduced. you might use `Outer<int>::InnerA().operator !=<int>(Outer<int>::InnerB())`. Non template friend functions is the solution (for ADL and making deduction a non problem).

Comment: @Jarod42 I didn't understand your reply when I first read it, but I just found a paper that confirms your statement and explains why.  I'll make a new answer to reflect this.  Thanks!