# How to write a commutable overloaded arithmetic operator for a template nested class?

Tags: c++, templates, nested, operator-overloading

I successfully built an overloaded operator+(**Global** left, **int** right) for a template class in global scope named **Global**.

```
template <typename T>
class Global {
public:
    Global operator+(const int& right) const
    {
        cout << "Using Global overloaded operator+" << endl;

        return *this;
    }
};
```

Since addition is commutative, I also created the other overloaded operator+(**int** left, **Global** right) to allow the commutable operation.

```
template <typename T>
Global<T> operator +(int left, Global<T> right)
{
    return right + left;
}
```

Here is my attempt to do the same thing for a Nested Class.

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested operator+(const int& right) const
        {
            cout << "Using Nested overloaded operator+" << endl;

            return *this;
        }
    };
};

template <typename T> // The following line is critical
typename Container<T>::Nested operator+(int left, typename Container<T>::Nested right)
{// Both 'typename' are necessary to avoid extra compilation errors
    return right + left;
}
```

Now when I try to execute the following code to test the operator overloads, I get some compilation errors when trying to use the commutable operator+ from the Nested class, mainly **"Error C2783 - 'Container::Nested operator +(int,Container::Nested)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'"**, but also **"Error E0349 - no operator "+" matches these operands"**.

```
int main(void)
{
    Global<int> global;

    global + 2; // Works perfectly
    2 + global; // Works perfectly

    Container<int>::Nested nested;

    nested + 2; // Works perfectly
    2 + nested; // Compilation Error C2783 and E0349

    system("pause"); // Everything works fine without the line above

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio 15.5.2 with **/std:c++latest** enabled. If possible, I would like the operator+ to be defined inside the Nested class definition.

Comment: `Global<T> operator +(int left, typename Global<T> right)` should be `Global<T> operator +(int left, Global<T> right)`. There is no need for `typename` there

Comment: The Global operator+ is completely fine. If you meant the Nested operator+, I tried removing the typenames to be "Container<T>::Nested operator+(int count, Container<T>::Nested iterator)". The compiler throws a lot of extra errors that have nothing to do with the operator+ such as **Error C2065 'global': undeclared identifier**. The same happens if I remove only one of the 'typename'.

Comment: with the `typename` in `Global<T> operator +` my compiler gives an error for unnecessary `typename`...

Comment: If I understood correctly, I tried to switch this line `typename Container<T>::Nested operator+(int left, typename Container<T>::Nested right)` into this `Container<T>::Nested operator+(int left, typename Container<T>::Nested right)`

Comment: You misunderstood then. I copy-pasted the **exact** code you posted. I meant to delete the `typename` in your function provided in the **second** block of code, which is: `Global<T> operator +(int left, typename Global<T> right)`. The `typename` **is wrong here**.

Comment: But the second block of code is already working perfectly, the problem happens when I try to use the Nested operator. Tried to change the second block of code as suggested but as expected nothing changes regarding the errors in the third/fourth block of code, even though the second block of code still works without the 'typename', let me remove it from the question to avoid extra confusions.

Comment: I'd recommend making both operator overloads non-members: `operator+(Global<T>, int)` and `operator+(int, Global<T>)`. Not only does it make the code look more symmetric, it can make a difference in behavior.  If an implicit conversion from the type of `x` to `Global<T>` exists, in the version with a member operator, `2+x` will work but `x+2` will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308213/workaround-for-non-deduced-context), the template deduction is far more complicated in this case than one might think. To fix this you can declare the function as `friend` inside your `Nested` class, like so:

```
template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
    class Nested {
    public:
        Nested operator+(const int& right) const
        {
            std::cout << "Using Nested overloaded operator+" << std::endl;

            return *this;
        }
        // moved here and declared as friend, instead of declaring it somewhere else
        friend Nested operator+(int left, Nested right)
        {
            return right + left;
        }
    };
};
```

By doing this, you also avoid using double `typename` and `Container<T>::` (*thanks @Jarod42*) in the signatue.

Comment: I understood that the extra `typename` in the Global class was unnecessary, let's remove it from the question since it has nothing to do with it. Thanks for your quick, well-formatted and correct answer.

Comment: @user2565020 agreed, I deleted the parts regarding it. Always happy to help